# Order of evaluation and @ sign in the PHP code segment?

Tags: php

Consider the following php segment code:-

```html
<?php

#Part-1
$a = 1;
$c = $a + $a++;
echo $c;

#Part-2
$a = 1;
@ $c = $a + $a++;
echo $c;

#Part-3
$a = 1;
$c = $a + $a + $a++;
echo $c;

#Part-4
$a = 1;
@ $c = $a + $a + $a++;
echo $c;
?>
```

The output of the above code segment is:
3233

Now my questions is following:-

1. How output is 3233 - explain breafly?

2. And what is the role of @ sign in the code segment?

3. If Part-1 code segment output is 3 but how Part-3 code segment output 3?

Comment: Its used to suppress any error messages - notice, warning or even fatal generated by the associated line of code.

Comment: The [@  sign is an error suppressor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php), however, weird behavior that...

Comment: Voted to reopen as OPs question (why does `@$c = $a + $a++;` return 2 while `@c = $a + $a++` return 3?) wasn't answered. [**Here is a simplified example**](https://eval.in/199046).

Comment: [From the manual about operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) `$a = 1;echo $a + $a++; // may print either 2 or 3`, it [actually depends on what version you use](http://3v4l.org/Rv0tY), but in short: your statement has no defined outcome. In short: because _"Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions are grouped, they do not specify an order of evaluation. "_, don't create these kind of statements.

http://3v4l.org/Rv0tY